# Application unpublished from Google Play Store but user still can add their review

Tags: google-play-store

I just came across such a strange thing from Google Play Store .

I unpublished my application from  Google play store 3 days ago. But i see users still adding their reviews. I cannot understand how Google is accepting their review even if my application is not on Google Play Store.
Its very strange to me about Google.

Can anyone unveil this secret of Google ! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existing app users will still be able to receive app updates, even if you unpublish your app. So a existing user can go through Google Play > My apps, and review your app. Only the new users are unable to find it.

Source:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en